# Java NullPointerError

Tags: java, sorting, nullpointerexception

This is a sorting algorithm test file. I am getting NullPointer error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.loadFiles(Test.java:28)
    at Test.main(Test.java:39)"
```

The problem seems to be with "`filecache[x].setName(nameOffiles[x]);`"
Please guide. Thanks.

```
import java.io.File;
public class Test {
   static File folder = new File("D:\\");
   static File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
   static String[] nameOffiles = new String[30];
   static long[] sizeOffiles = new long[30];
   static int i = 0;
   static MyFile filecache[] = new MyFile[30];
   public static void readFiles(){
      for (File file : listOfFiles) {
         if (file.isFile()) {
            nameOffiles[i] = file.getName();
            sizeOffiles[i] = file.length();
            i++;
         }
       }
       i = 0;
   }
   public static void loadFiles(){
      for(int x = 0; x <nameOffiles.length; x++){
         filecache[x].setName(nameOffiles[x]);
         filecache[x].setSize(sizeOffiles[x]);
      }
   }
   public static void testFiles(){
      Sorting sort1 = new Sorting();
      sort1.quickSort(filecache);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      readFiles();  
      loadFiles();
      testFiles();
      for(int x = 0; x < filecache.length; x++){
         System.out.println(filecache[x]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The likelihoods that whatever is at `filecache[x]` is `null`.  Looks like it's time to learn how to use a debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not initializing the objects in your `filecache` array, hence the `NullPointerException`. Try like this:

```
public static void loadFiles() {
    for(int x = 0; x < nameOffiles.length; x++){
        MyFile myFile = new MyFile();
        myFile.setName(nameOffiles[x]);
        myFile.setSize(sizeOffiles[x]);

        filecache[x] = myFile;
    }
}
```

Also, if you have more than 30 files, `readFiles` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Either initialize your arrays to have the same length as the number of files, or use collection types instead of arrays (preferred).

Answer (score 0):

Your filecache array may have been created with a size of 30, but each element in the array is null until you put something in it. So, `filecache[0].setName()` will throw a null pointer exception.

Make sure you add a new MyFile object at the required index in the array before trying to call methods on it.

```
for(int x = 0; x <nameOffiles.length; x++){
    if(filecache[x] == null) {
        filecache[x] = new MyFile();
    }
    filecache[x].setName(nameOffiles[x]);
    filecache[x].setSize(sizeOffiles[x]);
}
```